# How to convert all elements automatically in a list to a given object in Python

Tags: python, class

I want to create a list child class that can convert all elements automatically in it to an object no matter the element is create by init or append or extend. So by using both for loop or **getitem**. Here's a simple example code. What kind of magic method should I use?

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Object A with name {}'.format(self.name)    

class CustomerList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CustomerList, self).__init__(*args)        

c = CustomerList('a')
c.append('b')
c[0]   # Object A with name a
c[1]   # Object A with name b
for ele in c:
    print(c)
# Object A with name a  
# Object A with name b
```

Comment: What do you mean by converting the element into an object? Technically, everything is an object.

Comment: @TerryA obviously convert any object into a given type object, Typically, object A in this example, convert everything to A.

Comment: There's no one magic method that would do the job.  You'd have to override `__init__`, `__setitem__`. `append`, `extend`, and probably a few others I'm not thinking of at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you asking how to override `__append__`?

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Object A with name {}'.format(self.name)    

class CustomerList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CustomerList, self).__init__(*args)   
    def append(self,letter):
        super(CustomerList, self).append(A(letter))
```

I guess???.. but as mentioned in the comments if you want

```
my_custom_list.extend(["A","B","V"])
my_custom_list[2] = "A"
```

to work you will need to override

```
 def __setitem__(self,key,value): # cover a[2]='A'
     super(CustomerList,self).__setitem__(key,A(value))

 def extend(self,other):
     super(CustomerList,self).extend([A(val) for val in other])
```

of coarse you probably then need to override both `__add__,__iadd__` at a minimum as well

Comment: How to convert with the initialize case? and besides, if I want add extend so I have to override all methods?

Comment: All this actions is dealing with the input behavior of a list. Can we use some magic method to control output of list. For example, I don't care the real type in this list as long as when I take out an element it's can be converted to expected type.

Comment: you can use `__getitem__` maybe

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is: When you append a new item into the list, it is an object of class `A`. What you can do is override `list.append` function:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Object A with name {}'.format(self.name)    

class CustomerList(list):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(CustomerList, self).__init__(*args)  
    def append(self, arg):
        new_obj = A(arg)
        self.insert(len(self), new_obj)
```

Comment: reasonable answer ... although i think insert is O(N), while append is O(1) ... i think(+1 all the same)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Fair enough. I just assumed that you couldn't use the previous `append` function if you were overriding it, but you proved me wrong :P

Comment: How to convert with the initialize case? and besides, if I want add extend so I have to override all methods?

Comment: @TianchengLiu For inserting methods yes you would need to override them. I'm not sure what you mean by "convert with the intialize case", but remember when you do `A(arg)` is runs A's `__init__` by default

Comment: @TerryA . Yes override __init__ method to convert c = CustomerList('a') into object A. Thank you for your help.